# Inputing test cases into TestRail

Tags: php, http-request, testrail

Has anyone worked with TestRail? If so, I would love some help in figuring out to format the HTTP requests that I am supposed to send in order to create the test cases. I've looked over the documentation the TestRail API, but the documents aren't very clear.

What I am trying to do is take information from an Excel spreadsheet and the upload it into the TestRail program. I've been told that I need to pass each part of the test case (Title, Expected results, priority, etc.) as arguments within the http request. I'm just looking for some clarification. I'm using PHP to do all this, so if you could help, that would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one of the TestRail developers here. You need to submit the API arguments as POST arguments to TestRail as explained on our website:

http://docs.gurock.com/testrail-api/accessing

That is, you would send the API key as part of the URL (as a GET parameter) and submit all fields you would like to write as POST arguments (just like a web form). You can simply use the `curl` command line tool to test this (you can find an example in the link mentioned above) or you can use the curl library in PHP or any other HTTP framework to submit a request:

http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-curl-form-post/

I hope this helps.